# php curl: (60) SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have a VPS and I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway in my site. I have an SSL sertificate installed in my site (COMODO) and as instruced by the gateway providers, I have to establish a secure connection through cURL. 
The code is as follows:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $stringbuffer);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $s);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/home/site/ssl/certs/Cert.pem");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

this Cert.pem, I extracted it from their website (with chrome) and then converted it to pem through openssl. Now whenever I try to establish this connection, I get the error:

```
CURL ERROR: 60::SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I have access to php.ini so after a big search I tried to add the following to the ini file:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo="/home/site/ssl/certs/myCert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile="/home/site/ssl/certs/myCert.pem"
```

where myCert.pem is my website certificate which I extracted again as cer and then converted it to pem with openssl.

I also tried to add https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem in place of myCert in the ini file with no success.

Any ideas, and please don't ask me to turn off the verifypeer as I can't do so.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with issuer certificate doing amazon s3, I have two php.ini files and have added the path to the curl.cainfo and I still have the same problem